# Falsely accused from a co-worker

Tags: complaint, california, lying, unions

I received a falsely accused complaint from a co-worker for pushing and hitting her.
The accusation in fact comes right after another co-worker complaint about her best friend (aka her direct supervisor and my supervisor) because the supervisor gave her work to the lower level employee. I'm under California School unions. 
In the reprimanded documents, there are many errors that I can proof myself using my emails
How many witnesses do I need to have in order to shows that she had motives against me.

Comment: What is the question actually?

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable by this community as written.  I have voted to close pending improvements.

Answer (score 13):

> I received a falsely accused complaint from a co-worker for pushing and hitting her.

You are being accused of a criminal action under California law.  I would reach out to your union representative and also a lawyer if your union does not provide legal representation.

Comment: 1 vote from me... "Get a lawyer" is the only correct answer here

Comment: "Go to your union and they will get a lawyer, if necessary" is the correct answer here.